# Can't Connect to LocalHost Mysql Server

Tags: mysql

I recently installed mysql server and client, but I can't connect to the server. I get this message:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES/NO)

Whatever I do i will always get the same message.

I tried commenting `bind-address` but still the same thing.

Comment: How are you trying to connect?

Comment: I tried both terminal and GUI programs, in ubuntu. I mean no matter what i do, even if it to change the password i will always get the "access denied"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up a password for the root user during installation, then start the mysql client with the -p option, `mysql -u root -p`, and it should prompt you for a password.

If there's no password set, leave the `-p` off and it should log right in.

If you've somehow forgotten what the root password is, you can fix it by following these instructions... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I tried that many times, there is a password and i remember it, with or without -p it will give the error 1040, accessed denied..

Comment: Scratch that, error 1040 is not a password error. It's a too-many-connections error: http://rackerhacker.com/2008/06/24/mysql-error-1040-too-many-connections/

Comment: Resetting the system password? No i haven't done that, i'll try now, though i can see why would that be a problem.

Comment: Oh, sry i meant error 1045! "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
"